# How to connect Access-Excel data input

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to think of solutions to my problem.

I have:
A - A list of numbers in excel (lets say a uniqueID), this list changes every few hours

B - A table in Access that has every uniqueID with an additional column of information (lets say its a count , call it X).

My day-to-day workflow involves have an excel sheet full of uniqueIDs with a blank X column. Currently I am importing the excel sheet into access, running an update query then copying the information back into excel to send on to a colleague. I do this every few hours and its quite painful, I know there is a coding way I can do this easier and have been experimenting with the idea of a VBA macro that pulls data directly from the access table and fills in my column in excel.

Is this doable? Im not really sure how to go about it or even what to search in google for more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of Excel object, read required data, then dump X values back to xlsx using CopyFromRecordset function. Here is typical code:

```
Dim rs_data As DAO.Recordset
Dim xls_App As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim xls_WB As Object 'Excel.WorkBook
Dim xls_WS As Object 'Excel.Worksheet

Set xls_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xls_WB = xls_App.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\MyDataFile.xlsx")
Set xls_WS = xls_WB.Sheets("MyWorksheetWithData")

Set rs_data = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(str_SourceQuery)
xls_WS.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs_data
rs_data.Close
xls_WB.Save
xls_App.Quit
```

Also you can read the data from xlsx directly using SQL. Here is an example how to transfer data from Excel to existing Access table using SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (uniqueID, SomeOtherColumn) 
SELECT *
  FROM [MyWorksheetWithData$A1:B100] 
    IN "C:\Temp\MyDataFile.xls" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that should hopefully be just what I need to point me in the right direction